# for loop giving an error

Tags: shell, command-line

Current working directory is PATH2

ARG2=3

```
$ for i in {1..$ARG2}
  do
    cd FIXBILL_$i
    cp output.txt $PATH1
    cd $PATH1
    mv output.txt output_$i.txt
    cd $PATH2
 done
```

```
sh[3]: FIXBILL_{1..3}:  not found.
cp: cannot access output.txt: No such file or directory
mv: output.txt: cannot access: No such file or directory
```

it should take FIXBILL_1 , FIXBILL_2 & FIXBILL_3 but instead its taking FIXBILL_{1..3}. Please help.

Comment: Expansions only work with constants

Comment: Replace `for i in {1..$ARG2}` with `for i in $(seq 1 "$ARG2")` (beware of *, for example).

Comment: Note that the error message was produced by `sh`, a simpler shell that does not understand the `{1..3}` expansion, so it treats the characters as filename components. The `bash` shell supports `{1..3}`.

Comment: but the bash shell does not support `{1..$var}`